# Issues in recording a jnlp application through VUGEN

Tags: jnlp, loadrunner

I am facing issues while i am trying to record a JNLP application in LoadRunner. I have followed all step mentioned in 
http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM169714

But later on below another link is given http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM185190?resultsURL=
as per which we need to edit the batch file..... which batch file is we need to edit and path of the batch.

Could you please help me!

Comment: Is this a Java based app. you're referring to?